# webdriver exception on google colab: chrome failed to start, exited abnormally

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, chromium

I have already read a couple of threads about this problem but none of them really helped me so here goes. I am trying to use selenium webdriver on google colab. i had some problems installing it but finally with the code below, i was able to install it:

```
!pip install selenium
!apt-get update
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
wd.get("https://www.webite-url.com")
```

however, now when i run this two lines of codes:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

this is the error I get:

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium-browser is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

Comment: normally web browser uses local video card and monitor to display window. If you run code on server then it try to use video card and monitor in this server but server usually don't have video card and monitor - because nobody could see this screen (except server's admin). And this can make problem. Chrome can run without displaying window when you use option `headless` and then it can run on server. (Server without monitor is called "headless" because monitor looks like it head)

Comment: @furas i think the headless option is already there in the code am i right?

Comment: you have to use `headless` in every `webdriver.Chrome()` - which runs new browser.

Comment: can you show me how please? @furas

Comment: you already have it in your question - `webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)`. You have to use `chrome_options` with  `--headless` in every `webdriver.Chrome()`

Answer (score 1):

It runs on server which doesn't have video card and monitor so you have to always use `--headless` and maybe other options too

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)

driver.get("...your_url...")
```